Why is interior multiplication by $v$ an antiderivation implying $v\lrcorner\ \omega ^n = n(v\lrcorner\ \omega)\wedge\omega^{n-1}$?
In Proposition 22.8 of Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds it is written that

[For $V$ a $2n$-dimensional vector space, $v$ a vector in $V$ and $\omega$ a degenerate $2$-covector of $V$] interior multiplication by $v$ is an antiderivation, this implies
$$v\lrcorner\ \omega ^n = n(v\lrcorner\ \omega)\wedge\omega^{n-1}.$$

I can't see why this is the case.

My attempt: using the fact that (see Lemma 14.13)
$$v\lrcorner\ (\omega^n\wedge\omega) = (v\lrcorner\ \omega^n)\wedge\omega + \omega^n\wedge(v\lrcorner\ \omega),$$
a proof by induction fails as the inductive step yields
\begin{split}
v\lrcorner\ \omega^{n+1} & = \color{red}{(v\lrcorner\ \omega^n)}\wedge\omega + \omega^n\wedge(v\lrcorner\ \omega)\\
& = \color{red}{n(v\lrcorner\ \omega)\wedge\omega^{n-1}}\wedge\omega + \omega^n\wedge(v\lrcorner\ \omega)\\
& = n(v\lrcorner\ \omega)\wedge\omega^{n} + \omega^n\wedge(v\lrcorner\ \omega)\\
& = (n-1)(v\lrcorner\ \omega)\wedge\omega^{n}.
\end{split}

In your last step, when you make the swap, you don’t get a minus sign:
\begin{align}
\omega^n\wedge(v\,\lrcorner\,\omega)&=(-1)^{(2n)(1)}(v\,\lrcorner\,\omega)\wedge \omega^n=(v\,\lrcorner\,\omega)\wedge \omega^n,
\end{align}
so you should end up with an $(n+1)$ at the end, not $(n-1)$, thus completing the induction.
